# Google Maps load from DB with GeoLocation

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

So I have some working code which fetches results from my DB and displays them on a Google map. I also have some code which uses my location to place a marker on a Google map.

My issue is that when I add them together the page loads the results from the DB then I accept geoloaction and it centers the map to my location but doesn't display my marker and also removes the markers for the DB results.

Here is the DB result code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

  var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("/Models/phpsqlajax_genxml2.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is my geolocation code:

```
// Check if user support geo-location
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('nearMeMap'), {
      zoom: 11,
      scaleControl: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      center: geolocpoint,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

            // Place a marker
        var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: geolocpoint,
            map: map,
            title: 'Your Location',
            icon: 'https://mt.google.com/vt/icon?psize=20&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff330000&name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-blue.png&ax=44&ay=48&scale=1&text=%E2%80%A2'
        });

    });
}
```

Also I get this in the console:

```
ReferenceError: locations is not defined


for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `ReferenceError` already says, you do not have the variable `locations` defined in your geolocation code.